# Convert multiple rows to single row in R

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

Original table:

```
ID------REMARK

1------ A

2------ B

1-------AG

3-------V

2-------BS

1--------E

4--------B

4--------BS
```

---

Required table:

```
ID......REMARK

1-------A,AG,E

2-------B,BS

3-------V

4-------B,BS
```

---

and then list according to frequently occurring sequences:

```
REMARK......OCCURRENCES


A,AG,E-------1

B,BS---------2

V -----------1
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [**about Stackoverflow**](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and [**what to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). As you will find in these two links, you should "show your work", and "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results". Thanks.

Comment: And please don't use CAPITALS FOR NORMAL TEXT...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach. `dat` is the name of your data frame:

```
res1 <- aggregate(REMARK ~ ID, dat, paste, collapse = ",")
#   ID REMARK
# 1  1 A,AG,E
# 2  2   B,BS
# 3  3      V
# 4  4   B,BS

table(res1$REMARK)
# 
# A,AG,E   B,BS      V 
#      1      2      1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `plyr` solution:

```
library(plyr)
dt.agg <- ddply( dt, .(ID), summarise, Remark = paste( REMARK, collapse = ",", sep = "" )  )
ddply( dt.agg, .(Remark), nrow )

  Remark V1
1 A,AG,E  1
2   B,BS  2
3      V  1
```